# How to add a text label to a WireSphere Gizmo?

Tags: unity, editors

I’ve created a few WireSphere gizmos on my scene, and I’d like to add labels to them so I can easily identify which corresponds to what variable. However, by using **transform.position**, the label appears at the center (or pivot?) of the Game Object that has the gizmo. I’d like to display the label right at the edge of the WireSphere, but when I tried doing **transform.position * _radius**, the label appears many meters away from the gizmo. It seems that this could be solved with an offset value, but it has to be very high for it to work (like 20+).

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Get the local Transform. Else if an object is at 10/10/0 in the world, multiplying it with a radius is adding even more. And why multiply and not just add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean `transform.position + Vector3.up * _radius`?

You want to scale the offset, not scale the position. Otherwise an object at 0,0,0 gets no offset and an object at 1000,1000,1000 has its label flung thousands of units away.

Comment: You're absolutely right, lol. Thanks!